# How to reload an MVC page?

Tags: razor, model-view-controller, reload

This is an MVC razor page, that works fine on first load.
If I use a reload from javascript or even a refresh in the browser menu (Chrome), I get
Server Error in '/' Application.

```
>The view 'actionChangeUserSentence' or its master was not found or no view 
>engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
>~/Views/Conduct/actionChangeUserSentence.aspx
>~/Views/Conduct/actionChangeUserSentence.ascx
>~/Views/Shared/actionChangeUserSentence.aspx
>~/Views/Shared/actionChangeUserSentence.ascx
>~/Views/Conduct/actionChangeUserSentence.cshtml
>~/Views/Conduct/actionChangeUserSentence.vbhtml
>~/Views/Shared/actionChangeUserSentence.cshtml
>~/Views/Shared/actionChangeUserSentence.vbhtml
> and so on...
```

meaning the url string is considered a non MVC url.
I tried several possibilities to reload, including:

```
-location.reload();
-window.location.reload(false); with both false and true
-location.href = location.href;
-history.go(0);
```

By the way, the reason I need to refresh is that js drawing on a html canvas doesn't work except after full page (re)load, reason still unknown. But anyway, a browser menu refresh should of course always work, I guess...
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is the view name you are trying to reload 'actionChangeUserSentence'? Is that maybe a Post request that is being re-called vs the get for the view?

Comment: No, the wanted view is the same as it was originally before the reload.

Comment: @Hopeless: No, the wanted view is the same as it was originally before the reload.

Comment: In Chrome's address bar it reads at first load: 
"http://localhost:13062/Conduct/Conduct?...". When my cshtml line
  @using (Ajax.BeginForm("actionTryGetNewSystemSentence", "Conduct", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "OnTryGetNewSystemSentenceSuccess(data)" }))
 a bit later becomes active, it calls, verified, my js function OnTryGetNewSystemSentenceSuccess(data)

Comment: And this function in itself doesn't automatically cause a reload, but, after some necessary but simple commands in this function I try to cause a call to the controller  by the js line "jQuery.post('@Url.Action("actionJustReload", "Conduct")');" which I would expect to cause a call to 
        //[HttpGet]
        //[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult actionJustReload()
        {
            return View();
        }

Comment: Which would cause a reload, BUT this cs function is never called because the @Url.Action address is not resolved as expected but causes the browser error. Remember that a if  the function OnTryGetNewSystemSentenceSuccess(data) does NOT contain the reload via cs, that a Chrome mouse  menu based refresh leads to the same error in the browser address..

Comment: I made rather big progress, after discovering that the current url that was fetched from location.href was in mvc not the url of the last full reload of the page, but related to the last call url to the controller, which not necessarily results in a new view. So, I had to keep (even in sessionstorage) the url of the first full (re)load of the page, and when reload was necessary, assign this to location href. To get this url, I used the event DOMSubtreeModified, but that's only ok on Chrome.

Comment: Glad you made some progress. I understand about the last call to the controller. Why must you reload? Why can't you just call the controller method for Conduct again? Another thought, is that you could store the url in a hidden input on the page, and then get the value when you want to reload. That way you wouldn't need to use the session storage.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest put that code in on ready function  of drawing canvas may this will help you

Comment: Yes, you would get a an onready event, IF the wanted same page was reloaded, but the error is already in trying to cause THAT page to reload, as the browser thinks it needs to load another, nonexistent page. So the ready event is never called (except for the first view of the page).

Answer (score 0):

Use just an `Response.Redirect("/<your page>");`